# Apply a gradient to a listview in android

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to use a listview in my application with a gradient from the bottom. 
I do not want to use the gradient in the background, I like to use it in the listview. 
To try to explain better, I attached a picture of what I want.

[image]

The background will show images that will change.

I searched a lot and made ​​several tests, but without success. 
I appreciate any help.

Thanks and regards

Comment: On the container you put the changing background. 
Then you can put a ListView as wide and tall as the parent with the semitransparent gradient as its background. 
That's it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android has something built  in for that. It is called fading edge. The two XML properties are [android:fadingEdgeLength](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:fadingEdgeLength) and [android:requiresFadingEdge](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#fadingEdge). If you were hoping to have the image gradient change,  I don't think they are dynamic.